# How to get the value of a hidden field in Jquery DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

My code is listed below

```
$("#tblAdminUsers").dataTable({
                bProcessing: true,
                sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("FetchAdminUsers", "Admin")',
                aoColumns: [
                     { sTitle: "Id", bSortable: false, "bVisible": false },
                     { sTitle: "Email", bSortable: false, },
                     { sTitle: "Location", bSortable: false, },
                      { sTitle: "Status", bSortable: true, },
                       { sTitle: "UserType", bSortable: false, },

                     {
                         sTitle: "Actions",
                         bSortable: false,
                         mRender: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) { return '<i class="ui-tooltip fa fa-pencil actions clsEdit" style="font-size: 22px;" data-original-title="Edit" ></i> <i class="ui-tooltip fa fa-trash-o actions clsDelete" style="font-size: 22px;" data-original-title="Delete"></i>'; }
                     }
                ]

             });
```

my problem is, how to get the value of the hidden field(here it is Id) on edit or delete button click

Comment: check in html inspector what html is rendered for that column

Comment: You could add it to your <i> tag as an id, e.g: '<i id="edit-' + aData[0] + '" class="...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using datatables 1.10:

```
 var row_that_you_want = 1 //you need to determine this how ever you like
 var table = $('#tblAdminUsers').DataTable()
 var column_data = table.row(row_that_you_want).data()[0]
```

Comment: how to use this method in each function